# Closing a file without knowing its handle

Tags: python, file

I have a function (which I can't modify) that tries to open a file but throws an exception in the process (`blackbox` in my MWE, a function imported from a module in reality). I'm trying to write some exception handling code that would delete the garbage file that `blackbox` tried to write. However, I can't because the file is still open and I  don't know how to close it without knowing the file handle (`myfile`).

This is what my MWE looks like:

```
import os

def blackbox(mypath): # a function that I can't modify
    myfile = open(mypath, 'w')
    myfile.write('some text')
    myfile.flush() # to make sure 'some text' is actually written to disc file.
    raise Exception('An error occured')
    myfile.write('some stuff that will never be written')
    myfile.close()

def del_file(mypath):
    # *** put something here that will close the file ***
    os.remove(mypath) # throws an error because file is still in use
    return

mypath = 'g:/test.txt'
try:
    blackbox(mypath)
except: # all exceptions
    del_file(mypath) # clean up
    raise # raise whatever exception got thrown
```

On `os.remove(mypath)` I get the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'g:/test.txt'
```

Now my question:
**How can I close and delete the open file, knowing `mypath` but without manipulating `blackbox`?**
The code above is written for Windows 7 but I think answers should be applicable to all operating systems. You might have to change `mypath`.

Comment: Wait... this looks weird. Isn't the whole point of using a context guard (that `with ... ` stuff that you *don't* have to take care of properly opening / closing yourself?

Comment: I ran your code (changing filename to a local file) and it deleted the file properly. The file is closed when the `with` clause exits. Its not open when you get to the point of deleting it.

Comment: The function `blackbox` is incorrect.It attempts to close the same file twice.

Comment: btw, you don't need `myfile.close()` at the end. its handled for you by the `with` context.

Comment: The real ``blackbox`` must be doing something like storing the file handle in a global variable; garbage collection would have closed the file otherwise, after the exception is thrown.  Can't you just look at this imported module and see what it's actually doing?

Comment: That's interesting. I'm using Python 2.7 and Spyder with Anaconda on Win7 and the error gets thrown in both the IPython console and the Python console. Do you guys experience the same if that line is replaced by `myfile=open(mypath, 'w')`? Keep in mind my problem is with a completely different function (`snappy.ProductIO.writeProduct` from the European Space Agency's snappy module: [link](http://step.esa.int/docs/v5.0/apidoc/engine/)).

Comment: It still works for me. The file's reference count is decremented when the `blackbox` function exits - even in an exception. Assuming the function hasn't stashed a reference to the file object somewhere else, this means its reference count goes to zero. In c-based pythons, this will cause the object's `__del__` to be called and that closes the file.

Comment: I just tried this again and Error 32 was not thrown with the `with` block. So I changed the MWE to not have a `with` block. This doesn't resolve tdelaney's comment though. Not sure why I get a different behaviour.

Comment: The real blackbox module basically just calls the Java entity referenced by `org.esa.snap.core.dataio.ProductIO`. I haven't found the source code for that entity yet and I also don't understand Java.

Comment: Interestingly, `os.remove(mypath)` does delete the file when called from the shell after executing the script.

Comment: However, the following sequence of shell calls gives very strange results:
`blackbox(mypath)` returns `An error occurred`, as expected. 
`os.remove(mypath)` gives `Error 32`, like in the script
but `os.remove(mypath)` called again executes successfully.
I wish I could use this knowledge to solve my problem but calling `os.remove(mypath)` a second time in `del_file`, in an except block separated by `sleep(5)` does not succeed.
Now I'm completely lost as to how all this works and what happens why.

Comment: Could this be solved by running the `blackbox` function in a separate process or some other closed environment?